# Icon size to design for ImageViews in Custom Layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

Good day, Just a quick Question here. I have ready the icon design guidelines, but would like to be clear on what i want to do. For a  custom Layout (sw-360dp) which has an ImageView

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:src="@my icon here"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

what will be  the best size to design an icon so that i don't lose sharpness, taking into consideration that in other layouts  which use ListView or other ImageViews, the ImageView could be smaller or bigger.What am asking is, can i just design one big enough icon and let android do the sizing on the ImageViews as required by the different layouts or should i target a specific size. Also taking into consideration, designing for different screen sizes   and densities. Hope i am clear on this. Many Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

> Try [nine patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) as they are normally used for icons you wouldn't
>   need large images and worry about large screen displays at the same
>   time

[image]

Comment: thanks for the info. Any other ideas, because i read somewhere that Nine-Patch should be avoided if possible. Thanks anyway.  would have a look to that.

Comment: and who told you that ? One of my application is listed at second number at Google TV's official Blog and i haven't used any non - nine patched image for icon in that.